# How to get first & last day of current week/month

Tags: android, datetime, kotlin

I had a requirement where I need to get the first & last day of the week/month and also can change the week/month to next or previous week/month

Comment: Which programming language are you using? Or is it a completely open task?

Comment: Kotlin answer will be preferable

Comment: Consider using [java.time, the modern Java date and time API](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/datetime/). Search for how, this has been asked and answered before.

Answer (score 1):

Use this Utils which use [joda-time](https://github.com/JodaOrg/joda-time) lib

### DateUtils.kt

```
import org.joda.time.DateTime
import org.joda.time.DateTimeConstants
import org.joda.time.format.DateTimeFormat

object DateUtils {

fun getCurrentWeekStartEndDate(): StartEndDate {
    return StartEndDate(
            DateTime.now().withDayOfWeek(DateTimeConstants.SUNDAY).minusWeeks(1),
            DateTime.now().withDayOfWeek(DateTimeConstants.SATURDAY)
    )
}

fun getNextWeekStartEndDateTime(currentDate: DateTime): StartEndDate {
    return StartEndDate(
            currentDate.withDayOfWeek(DateTimeConstants.SUNDAY),
            currentDate.withDayOfWeek(DateTimeConstants.SATURDAY).plusWeeks(1)
    )
}

fun getPreviousWeekStartEndDateTime(currentDate: DateTime): StartEndDate {
    return StartEndDate(
        currentDate.withDayOfWeek(DateTimeConstants.SUNDAY).minusWeeks(1),
        currentDate.withDayOfWeek(DateTimeConstants.SATURDAY)
    )
}

fun getCurrentMonthStartEndDate(): StartEndDate {
    return StartEndDate(
            DateTime.now().dayOfMonth().withMinimumValue(),
            DateTime.now().dayOfMonth().withMaximumValue()
    )
}

fun getNextMonthStartEndDateTime(currentDate: DateTime): StartEndDate {
    return StartEndDate(
            currentDate.plusMonths(1).dayOfMonth().withMinimumValue(),
            currentDate.plusMonths(1).dayOfMonth().withMaximumValue()
    )
}

fun getPreviousMonthStartEndDateTime(currentDate: DateTime): StartEndDate {
    return StartEndDate(
        currentDate.minusMonths(1).dayOfMonth().withMinimumValue(),
        currentDate.minusMonths(1).dayOfMonth().withMaximumValue()
    )
}

data class StartEndDate(val startDate: DateTime, val endDate: DateTime)

fun DateTime.toDefaultDateTimeString(dateTimeFormat: String) : String {
    return DateTimeFormat.forPattern(dateTimeFormat).print(this)
}
}
```